# Why can I log std::u16strings in Boost.Log without issue on Linux and Mac, but not on Windows?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I am trying to log std::u16strings encoded in UTF-16 via Boost.Log's BOOST_LOG_SEV macro, like this:

```
std::u16string u16str(u"Hello, world!");
BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg,normal) << u16str;
```

On Linux and Mac, the logger does the right thing automatically and converts the string to a UTF-8 encoded std::string, using the code in https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/develop/include/boost/log/detail/code_conversion.hpp by way of https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/develop/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp and https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/develop/include/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp.

Here's a trace of the code path on Linux:

```
boost::log::v2_mt_posix::operator<< <boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_record_ostream<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> > > (strm=..., value=...)
 
boost::log::v2_mt_posix::operator<< <char16_t, std::char_traits<char16_t>, std::allocator<char16_t> > (strm=..., str=...)
 
boost::log::v2_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::formatted_write<char16_t> (...)
 
boost::log::v2_mt_posix::aux::code_convert<char16_t, char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > (...)
```

However, on Windows, I get the following compile-time error:

```
boost\log\utility\formatting_ostream.hpp(965): error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
        with
        [
            T=std::u16string
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(466): note: could be 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(441): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(const void *)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(423): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(long double)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(405): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(double)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(387): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(float)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(369): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned __int64)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(351): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(__int64)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(333): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned long)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(315): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(long)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(296): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned int)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(270): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(int)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(251): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(unsigned short)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(217): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(short)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(199): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(bool)'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(194): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(189): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(184): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\ostream(461): note: or       'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator <<<void>(std::nullptr_t)'
boost\log\utility\formatting_ostream.hpp(965): note: while trying to match the argument list '(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>, T)'
        with
        [
            T=std::u16string
        ]
boost\log\sources\record_ostream.hpp(428): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'basic_formatting_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> &operator <<<formatting_ostream_type,T>(StreamT &,T &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=std::u16string,
            StreamT=formatting_ostream_type
        ]
test.cpp(20): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'basic_record_ostream<char> &operator <<<basic_record_ostream<char>,std::u16string>(StreamT &,T &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            StreamT=basic_record_ostream<char>,
            T=std::u16string
        ]
        ]
```

I can get around this by specifying my own overloaded << operator which does the conversion, but I am curious as to why Windows can't use an existing overload like Linux and Mac do. Could this be a bug in Boost.Log? Thanks!

Comment: The error message says no overload of `operator<<` is found that accepts a `std::u16string` streamed to a `std::ostream`. Which makes sense, because `std::basic_ostream<char>` (aka `std::ostream`) only accepts `std::basic_string<char>` (aka `std::string`) and not `std::basic_string<char16_t>` (aka `std::u16string`). Hence why Boost converts to UTF-8 `std::string` on Linux and Mac. So this is clearly a bug in Boost's implementation that it doesn't do the same conversion on Windows (or equivalent, ie using `std::wcout` with `std::wstring` instead, since Windows consoles don't handle UTF-8 well).

Comment: Support for `char16_t` and `char32_t` in Boost.Log is predicated on support for these types by the compiler and the standard library (in particular, `std::codecvt` specializations for these character types must be supported). This support is indicated by the macros defined by Boost.Config, such as `BOOST_NO_CXX11_CHAR16_T` and `BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_CODECVT`. Check the preprocessed output to see if those macros are defined.

Comment: I think the issue is this: https://github.com/boostorg/config/blob/c3de80c2efa69c10dcad7c7ffa37047c3d4cf49e/include/boost/config/stdlib/dinkumware.hpp#L232

This piece of code was put in when VC didn't fully support the necessary codecvt facets, and wasn't removed when Microsoft fixed the issue. I am working to confirm this; if this is indeed the problem; I will open a issue in github.

Comment: Opened https://github.com/boostorg/config/issues/391